# DLL call to a method involving strncpy()

Tags: c++, dll, strncpy, silktest

I have created a DLL with following methods:

```
typedef struct names {
  const char* name1;
  const char* name2;
} rNames;

typedef struct useNames {
   rNames fullName;
} rUseNames;

rUseNames finalName;

int set_name() {
  finalName.fullName.name1 = "Alfred";
  finalName.fullName.name2 = "Allen";
  return 1;
}

int __stdcall get_name(char* first, char* last) {
  strncpy((char*)first, finalName.fullName.name1, 
     strlen(finalName.fullName.name1));
  strncpy((char*)last, finalName.fullName.name2, 
     strlen(finalName.fullName.name2));
  return 1;
}
```

I am calling `get_name` via SilkTest as below:

```
ansicall int get_name(out string fname, out string lname); //dll method 
//declaration

STRING name = SPACE(256) //This initialises the name to 256 blank characters
STRING lname = SPACE(256)
get_name(name, lname)

print(name)
print(lname)
```

The Problem:

I am getting a **blank/empty string** as output and NOT "Alfred Allen". Ideally, `name` should be filled with the content Alfred and `lname` with Allen.

NOTE: Consider that `set_name()` is being called internally and the name is already set before the dll call is made.

Comment: Your `strncpy` calls do not null-terminate the output, maybe this is a problem

Comment: Is there a way to null terminate 'first' and 'last' dynamically?

Comment: @Corleone: Yes, you need to copy strlen+1 to copy the terminating null.  Note that you are abusing strncpy - used like this, it is not doing anything other than memcpy.  (Also strncpy is almost never the function you want - it doesn't necessarily null terminate, and will fill the buffer with null characters if the buffer is too big.)

Comment: I did use strncpy and defined the size to copy as strlen+1. Still getting the same issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure finalName.fullName.name1 and finalName.fullName.name2 are getting set? Please ensure that.
To null terminate you can do
    first[strlen(finalName.fullName.name1)] = '\0';

Comment: Agreed. Null termination isn't a problem here. Perhaps, the names are getting set and then being reset internally. I will debug around this. Thanks!

Comment: u can mark this as correct if u found this helpful in solving your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int __stdcall get_name(char* first, char* last) {

ansicall int get_name(out string name); //dll method declaration
```

So the first has two parameters, the second has one. They clearly don't match. How do you expect to get anything useful here?

Also, your test doesn't appear to call `set_name`, so `finalName` will only hold null pointers.

Comment: Edited the question. Please have a look.

Comment: @Corleone : I think it is the last sentence that is the actual answer.